# Search for records in elastic search with set of values for each field.

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I have a set of records in elastic search
I want to compare 1 specific records (I have it with me in a variable) with rest of the records present in the index.

I want to compare values for each field individually with the values from the record that i have.

For eg.
If i have

```
{
  "person" : [
    {
      "name" : "asd",
      "awdawD" : "asdawd"
    },
    {
      "name" : "adw ed",
      "awdawD" : "asdawd"
    },
    {
      "name" : "a wra",
      "awdawD" : "asdawd"
    },
    {
      "name" : "ca eyy",
      "awdawD" : "asdawd"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my record is

```
[
  {
    "name" : "asd",
    "awdawD" : "asdawd"
  },
  {
    "name" : "s tr",
    "awdawD" : " tjy"
  }
]
```

I want to compare name with name, awdawD with awdawD and get the result.

Since I have an array of Persons, will i have to create a loop for each element in the records I have, to compare it with the records in elastic search?

How can I do this in elastic search with out the loop ?

Comparing each name and awdawD individually.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably not the elegant solution you're looking for (which I don't think exists), but you could always do something like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "or": {
               "filters": [
                  {
                     "and": {
                        "filters": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "asd"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "awdawD": "asdawd"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "and": {
                        "filters": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "s tr"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "awdawD": " tjy"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

or this

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "name": "asd"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "awdawD": "asdawd"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "must": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "name": "s tr"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "awdawD": " tjy"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Both of these queries return only your first document (one or the other may be preferable depending on your analysis setup).

Here is some code I used to test it out:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/52de7f75e685486a63d18bd387cbb02d03cc6feb

Comment: I made an array of more like this queries. but I was searching for some thing like grouping all in one query